# Xamarin forms URL binding on Image

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Image in my xaml in which the source is a URL that Iam binding.The URL from json will be like this   : "**/images/Uploads/e0111.png**". I have the URL in my Common values stored class as CommonValues.URL. How can I add this "CommonValues.URL" before the json at the time of binding?  So that the source for Image will be http://example.com//images/Uploads/e0111.png.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `Uri`

```
var myUrl= new Uri(CommonValues.URL + "images/Uploads/e0111.png");
```

If `string` than

```
var myUrl=CommonValues.URL + "images/Uploads/e0111.png";
```

Or you can do it like this in your `ViewModel` or `Page`

```
public string Url => string.Format("{0}{1}", CommonValues.URL,"/images/Uploads/e0111.png");
```

Then in XAML:

```
<Button Text="{Binding Url}"/>
```

Comment: Bro how can I do this in xaml?

Comment: Create one public property `myUrl` in your viewmodel & than pass it to xaml file. It doesn't seem that you can do it from xaml.

Comment: let me check bro

Answer (score 1):

You can use a converter, which will allow you to reuse in all your views/application

```cs
public class UrlConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter implementation

    public object Convert (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var test = value as string; 
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(test))  
        {
            return CommonValues.URL + test;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack (object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then, in your page:

```xml
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <converter:UrlConverter x:Key="UrlConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Image Source="{Binding YourProperty, Converter={StaticResource UrlConverter}}"/>
```